# Wordpress HTML DOM Output Change via Hook

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have been trying to find a way to alter the final HTML DOM output (i.e., after JS script adjusts the HTML output) before it gets rendered on the browser.

I found a hook in Wordpress called 'template_redirect' which works well if I want to change the HTML output before JS gets executed but not after. So the before JS script execution, all I see is the JS name only from this hook.

Here's the problem that I'm trying to solve.  In my wordpress blog, I'm including a JS script from third-party and this JS is inserting extra tags (such as Schema.org tags regarding that their organization - Schema organization tags).  It is about 3000 characters long and it is bloating my webpage.  I would like to remove any extra tags that gets attached to my final HTML (it is getting added before `</html>` tag) before shown in the browser.

Note that I don't see these extra tags when I do view source and they show up only when I do inspect element from Chrome or FF.

Any suggestions on how to remove the HTML DOM after JS execution but before it is shown on the browser via Wordpress hooks or any other way?

Thanks, JK

Comment: This is not how it works. Wordpress nor any other CMS/Web Application can't change the output after sending it to the client. The solution is removing that third-party script. Why are using a script that generates something that you don't want?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I don't want to remove the JS because it is serving a purpose but it is adding some extra tags as advertisement visible only when I do inspect or 'Fetch as Google' option from Webmaster tool.  I understand that it may not be Wordpress hook - how else we can drop it from any via custom JS scripts that can be written?

Comment: Well, the answer depends on how the script works. There is always a way, but personally I wouldn't use something that has unwanted side-effects in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

JS is executed in the users browser not on the sever(in almost all cases). You can either remove the tags after they are rendered using more JS(which won't really help any "bloat"), or take a look at the code for the plugin you are using and alter the plugin

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  The JS file gets dynamically executed from elsewhere since I don't control the source code it.  So from Wordpress, I'm directly refering to the JS from the third-party website.  From JS suggestion, could you provide some code sample on how to do it?

Comment: Do you have a link to the site or an example that shows the extra data you want to remove? Also, what's the name of the plugin?

Comment: Here you go.  [link]<a href="//yummly.com" rel="nofollow" class="YUMMLY-YUM-BUTTON">Yum</a>
<script src="https://www.yummly.com/js/widget.js?wordpress"></script>[link]
This adds extra organization schema.org at the bottom of the final HTML.

Comment: @JKK ok, how about a link to your site or an example that shows the extra data you want to remove?

Comment: and is this the plugin(https://wordpress.org/plugins/yummly-rich-recipes/)? You only sent the JS

Comment: No, it is just that 1 JS only - there is no plugin.  You can place this JS anywhere you want the YUM button to appear.  This is the code generated by this JS at the end of the HTML page.

Comment: I don't know how I can paste that big text here.  The comment box can hold only 550+ odd characters only.

Comment: OK - I placed the output text in a file here [link]http://www.filedropper.com/yumm-org[link]

Comment: If you look, it is within an iframe. None of that is being place into your site.

Comment: ok - what does that mean?  It is still a part of the page that the browser loads up.  Is there anyway I can remove that the whole iframe?

Comment: You can remove the iframe by removing the button. The button itself is within the iframe as well. As far whether or not it is part of the page, yes and no. It is loaded by the browser, but it is accessing html from another site and displaying it on you site through the iframe. But you can not really alter/modify anything within the iframe.

Comment: Yes, I'm fine with the button showing in I-FRAME.  It is the extra text got added to the bottom of the HTML.  Did you get a chance to see the file dropper link that I pasted above.  That text is not in I-FRAME and that's what I want to remove from the final HTML.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding me. I created a page using the same exact YUM button from Yummly and then inspected the page source. The text you showed me in the filedropper link is displayed within the iframe that contains the button. Unless you are going to post the URL to the page where you claim it is not in the iframe, I can only assume that the text you are referring to is always displayed in an iframe like in my text.

Comment: thanks for trying it on a page from your end.  Please inspect the HTML from Chrome or FF.  Right click anywhere on the page and choose 'Inspect'.  In the elements tab, go all the way to the bottom of the page and you will notice the text that I'm referring to (after the html end tag).  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99250/discussion-between-hopkins-matt-and-jkk).